# Set up a pin programmatically on a Telerik Rad Map control

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I am trying to set programmatically the pinner (as the image) on a Telerik Rad Map control and it does not work. The following code creates a circle on map:

```
        <telerik:RadMap>
            <telerik:InformationLayer x:Name="informationLayer">
                <telerik:InformationLayer.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Ellipse telerik:MapLayer.Location="{Binding}"
                                Width="20"
                                Height="20"
                                Stroke="Red"
                                StrokeThickness="3"
                                Fill="Transparent">
                            <telerik:MapLayer.HotSpot>
                                <telerik:HotSpot X="0.5"
                                    Y="0.5" />
                            </telerik:MapLayer.HotSpot>
                        </Ellipse>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:InformationLayer.ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:InformationLayer>
        </telerik:RadMap>
```

And this the code of the appropriate event:

```
  this.informationLayer.Items.Add(loc);
```

I also know how to set up the pinner manually in the XAML:

```
<telerik:InformationLayer>
                        <telerik:MapPinPoint telerik:MapLayer.Location="25.098466, 55.161499"
                                Text="Start"
                                ImageSource="/Images/pin2.png" Width="60" Height="60"  >
                            <telerik:MapPinPoint.HotSpot>
                                <telerik:HotSpot X="0.5"
                                    Y="1" />
                            </telerik:MapPinPoint.HotSpot>
                        </telerik:MapPinPoint>
                    </telerik:InformationLayer>
```

But I need to do it from code behind. How can I do it?